# Porting to Django, Support for legacy user database

Tags: django, md5, legacy-database

I am porting my website from raw php to Django. I have used inspectdb to create models for the existing database. The problem that has come is that earlier I was registering the users and saving their passwords as a md5 hash md5($pass) and Django does not support this md5 version.

Is there a way I can support my legacy database of user and for new users make use of the powerful Django user model that supports user profile?

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation on [authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/authbackends/) and [writing an authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend).